# What's a good way to get started in Space Station 13?

Tags: space-station-13

After seeing some interesting questions about space station 13 here on Arqade I tried to give it a try.

So far I:

- Spent half an hour trying to get out of the arrivals shuttle with no luck, then the station self destructed.
- On my second attempt got out of the shuttle, only to be shot by some form of robot as soon as I stepped out.
- Started a game as a security agent, got sedated, dragged into a dark tunnel and strangled to death.
- Started another game as security agent, saw a robot assault what looked like a crew member. Tried to shoot the robot with a stun gun (not successful), only to have the robot tell me I was being stupid and the crew member some form of changeling. (At this point I closed the game in panic)
- Started a game as a less ambitious janitor, mopping corridors until half an hour later the station self destructed.

Obviously, I don't seem to be qualified just yet to enjoy the exciting space station life. What's a good place for a beginner to start?

Comment: Can't wait for the remake of this, it sounds really interesting.

Comment: Aren't there a few remakes going on right now?  I know there's one with a different name entirely and in 3D, something like Centrillion I think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the station! Or as Magneto puts it, welcome to DIE!

You're going to die a lot on Space Station 13.  Even on a good round, when you do everything right and know all the rules, there's a very good chance you will die in some unexpected way.  It's a lot like Nethack or Dwarf Fortress in that way.

The good news is that when you DO die, there are ways you can keep participating despite your death!  For one, in the OOC tab, you have the option to become a Ghost and observe the action taking place around the station.  This is a good way to get acquainted with the layout of said station, and to see what some of the things going on might be.

Certain servers have a wikipedia page that offer their own "beginner's guide", which you can usually access with the Wiki tab.  These guides will get you started with some basic knowledge on how things work.

Basically, you interact with the world by clicking on things.  You click on things to pick them up, you click on things to use them on other things, and you click on a thing in one hand on a thing in another hand (Switch hands by clicking the hand you want to use) to use the thing on the other thing.  And there are a LOT of ways to interact with things!  It can be pretty daunting, especially on your first time, so I do recommend finding at least one guide that can explain basic controls.  There are a few out there, such as the Baystation 12 one or the /tg/ station one.  But find one that works for you.

A  good way to get acquainted with the station and to get around it (You walk into a door with the arrow keys to go through it, by the way) is to be an assistant.  They have basically no responsibilities, and access to various maintenance shafts with interesting things to pick up and put on (to the left of your screen is an icon that opens up your character doll, and allows you to put on various things).  You will still probably be a target of someone, but with each death you'll learn a little more about how the station functions.

Once you get your legs for the stations, start picking a few civilian jobs to get your feet wet.  Learn to mix drinks as a bartender to learn the basics of mixing liquids, or be a chef and learn the basics of adding items together to make other interesting items.  Grow plants in Botany and learn how to harvest mad crops, be a librarian and have nothing really to do of importance.  Be a Cargo Tech (Recommended!) and deliver important supplies around the station.  Most importantly, don't get frustrated if you die a few times.  Life is fast and loose and can even be returned to you in a few fun ways.

And by all means, ask people how to do things (In character!  Or without referring to what you're doing if you're doing it in OOC, or click the admin tab and ask an admin for help).  In fact, talking things out with people and acting as clueless as you really are not only helps you learn to do different jobs, but builds roleplaying ambiance that really is at the heart of enjoying Space Station 13.

Answer (score 4):

The first place to start is the relevant wiki. Each server is either derived from a goonstation or a /tg/ server branch, and so there is a different wiki for each.

Use the wiki to familiarize yourself with basic controls, and test them out in-game. It sounds like you have a grasp of them already.

Next, use the wiki and pick one of the lower level science jobs to try. I suggest something like botanist or roboticist. When you spawn, immediately go to your lab following the map on the wiki. While you may be able to figure out how to do the job just from the wiki, you hopefully can ask someone else in that role (there can be multiple people in the low level science roles). Start with the basics, making food for the cook or turning people into cyborgs. From there, you can try a different job or try the more advanced mechanics and concepts.

Many people advise that new players start as an assistant. This is terrible advice, because assistants can't do virtually anything without breaking space law, unless they get permission from someone else. Not only that, but they also spend their time wandering the halls, which is where the chaos starts. Its usually much safer in a science lab.

Comment: Science can be a little intimidating at first.  Especially if you don't have someone to guide you along. 

Not to mention it's relatively easy to die in Xenobio or Toxins.  Especially Toxins.

Comment: That's why i didn't recommend either of those in particular. I should say that cook and bartender are pretty good as well if people don't want to do science. I just really wanted to warn people away from the common advice to start as assistants.

Comment: Understandable, and a good job that they can sink their teeth into will teach them a lot more about being part of the crew than being an assistant.  I never really considered "Botany" to be part of the science team though, and I haven't even done Robotics, so I can't attest to how easy/hard it is. Though it's (usually) not targeted for bombings, so maybe at least somewhat safe.

Comment: @zibbobz yeah apparently nobody else counts it as part of 'science' either, even though it behaves similarly in most respects (isolated to a lab, relatively complex interactions with items but limited interaction with humans, etc)

Comment: Not sure what server you play on, but the one I play on has it directly connected to the kitchen, so it's usually considered part of the "Civilian" roles.  Probably because the really 'cool' options (mutated plants) are largely optional, and you can get by on a station with just one botanist growing basic food.  There also isn't much 'discovery' in growing mutated food, though there is a bit, so I can see why you would group it with science.  And though it doesn't really interact with the other Science departments, the same could be said of Toxins.

Answer (score 3):

Don't start as security, start as something like medical doctor, or shaft miner.

Throw yourself into it, don't be afraid to ask questions from the admins using the "adminhelp" command. Know where the wiki is, you're going to have it open. A lot. If you get killed, and an admin replies "valid" don't go screaming in OOC or in dead chat that you got griefed, randomly killed, etc. For the love of god, read the rules for the server you're on, many servers have different ways of running things and it can be frustrating when someone gets banned for one thing on one server, when they came from another server and it was okay to do that thing.

Thats the basics, pretty much.

Oh, I'd avoid using OOC to ask questions about in game events or how to use some items, that's best using the adminhelp command.

Comment: Medical can be a bit hectic, and shaft miner can be reeeeally boring and not teach you a lot about the station.  Everything else you say, ESPECIALLY about keeping the wiki open, I agree with.

Comment: I only suggest mining because you get a space suit with decent armor, and a mining pick which is decent for self defense. Not only that but nobody really expects you to do your job anyways.

Comment: True. (Though as an occasional RnD player, it can be quite frustrating to have no special minerals to work with)  And it definitely teaches you about wearing special suits, resource management and combination, and rarely places you in any major danger unless you run into aliens on the asteroid...which you might. But it can also be...really...really...dull.  Though for safety from the station at large, nothing beats it.