# How do I buckle myself in?

Tags: space-station-13

After some [less successful sessions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/133000/whats-a-good-way-to-get-started-in-space-station-13), I finally managed to survive on the station until the emergency shuttle arrived. Better yet, I was even able to locate it and get in on time.

However, when the shuttle departs I get knocked to the ground. I can see other people buckling themselves in, so I'm assuming the reason I get slammed around a bit is that I didn't strap in myself?

How do I buckle in? I tried dragging myself onto a chair, or just clicking it but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move into the same square as the chair then drag your character onto it. You can also buckle someone in if you're adjacent to them this way- especially useful if they're handcuffed.

Comment: It can be a little tricky when you're on top of the chair, because either your character will obscure the chair, or the chair will obscure your character, but this IS the right way to buckle in. And the reason buckling someone to a chair while cuffed is useful? They can no longer run away if you stop pulling them.